# How do I get rid of this gray line at the bottom of the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am trying to create a 40x40 grid using multiple JPanels and after I managed to create it, there is this empty space at the bottom of the JFrame.

```
public drawBoard() {
    
    createMap(40, 40);
}

public void createMap(int maxX, int maxY) {
    String [ ][ ] map = new String [maxX][maxY];

    //create 40 panel for the snake to move around in
    for (int i=1; i < maxX; i++) {
        for (int j=1; j < maxY; j++) {

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            add(panel);
            panel.setPreferredSize(pref_size);
            String name = String.format("[%d, %d]", i, j);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(maxX, maxY, 1, 1)); //change gap to 0 after tests are done
            setBackground(Color.GRAY); 
            panel.setName(name);

        }
    }
}

private static void createFrame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new drawBoard());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
};
```

[image]

Comment: try `frame.setSize(100,100);` ... adjust values to fit

Comment: Looks like there were 39x39 instead of 40x40 on the grid, thank you for the help anyway

Comment: yes,  you're starting at i=1 and j=1 instead of i=0 and j=0 .... odd number of squares are an advantage because there is a middle square

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer, looks like it was a 39x39 grid instead of 40x40, once changed the grid just fell into place with no blank spaces.[all good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEIrY.png)

Comment: Plus one for solving it yourself and reporting the solution, but note that the problem would have been more easily solved by starting with a much smaller grid of (e.g.) 5x5.